# Hair Sticking Through Face

Tags: particles

I can't figure out why, but my hair is sticking through my character's face weirdly.
[image: Face]
As you can see, it's sticking out around the eyes, but if you look in particle edit mode...
[image: Particle Edit]
There's no obvious hair strands sticking through the mesh... I tried many times to comb it up, and then back down, but it always does the same thing. I set the collision settings to 0.5 for inner and outer... Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using interpolated children. Those try to place children between hair strands. Simplest case: The hair closest to the current hair has a deformation slightly different than the original, if a child is placed half way between them, it will have a 50:50 mix between both positions and deformations. That can easily cause bad results, especially when 2 hairs are fairly close together, but combed in the opposite direction, the interpolation can look like what you're seeing. For longer hair simple children are usually the better option.

Comment: I was using Simple, but it causes some of the children to float in the air... Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: He explains the child settings and combing pretty well. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpVyTc_72z0

Comment: Thank you very much, I was watching videos like crazy but most don't explain very well! Haha